# Prononciation du subjonctif et du présent de l'indicatif

Tags: prononciation, subjonctif, indicatif

Quand un verbe s'écrit de la même façon au présent de l'indicatif et au subjonctif, prononce-t-on les deux formes de la même façon ?

> Il **travaille** ici mais sa gérante veut qu'il **travaille** ailleurs.

Est-ce qu'on prononce les deux « **travaille** » de la même façon ?

Si on doit prononcer les deux mots de façon légèrement différente, quand quelqu'un essaie de prononcer un verbe au subjonctif mais qu'il le dit au présent du indicatif parce que c'est difficile de le prononcer correctement, est-ce qu'une erreur comme ça sonne mal aux oreilles des francophones?

Comment: pour une telle question, cette annexe au wiktionnaire est indispensable; tous les prononciations des verbes y sont, au même page : http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Conjugaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais/travailler

Answer (score 4):

Dans tous les cas où les verbes s'écrivent de la même façon au présent de l'indicatif et au subjonctif, ils se prononcent exactement de la même façon. Il n'y a aucune distinction.